# Need help getting my Java Rock-Paper-Scissors game to compile

Tags: java, debugging

I've been trying to get this code to work for the past week now, and every time I make one change I end up with more bugs. Can anyone help figure out where I've gone wrong?

The code is split up into two files: a runner class, and a class with all the methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RPSRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = "";
        String player = "";

        RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors();

        System.out.print("What is your name? : ");
        player = keyboard.next();

        out.print("type in your prompt [R,P,S] :: ");
        response = keyboard.next();

        game.setPlayers();
        game.convertUserInput(response);
        game.setPlayerChoice(response);
        game.computerThink();
        game.determineWinner();


    }
}
```

The method class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
    private String playerName; //used to set player's name
    private int playChoice; //player's choice as a number
    private int compChoice; //computer's choice as a number
    private int playerNumber;

    Random rand = new Random(); //allows useage of random methods

    public RockPaperScissors()
    {
        //sets everything to null, prepare for incoming calculations
        playerName = "";
    }

    public RockPaperScissors(String player)
    {

        playerName = player;
    }

    public void setPlayers(String player)
    {
        //good ol mutator method
        playerName = player;
    }

    public String convertUserInput(String response)
    {
        //Convert R, P, S to integer using switch case
            //If invalid input, set to -1

            switch(response) {
                case "R": playChoice = 0;
                    break;
                case "P": playChoice = 1;
                    break;
                case "S": playChoice = 2;
                    break;

                default: playChoice = -1;
            }
    }

    public boolean setPlayerChoice(String response)
    {
        //TODO set playChoice to convertUserInput
        //return (playChoice != -1)

        playChoice = convertUserInput(response);
        return(playChoice != -1);
    }

    public int computerThink()
    {
        //Use Math.random from 0-2 inclusive
        //return it all in one statement so
            //return Math.random(whatever);

            return rand.nextint(2);
    }

    public String determineWinner()
    {
        String winner="";

        compChoice = computerThink();

        switch(compChoice) {
            case 0:
                if(playChoice == 1){
                    winner = playerName;
                } else if(playChoice == 2) {
                    winner = "Computer";
                } else if(playChoice == 0) {
                    winner = "Tie";
                }

            case 1:
                if(playChoice == 1) {
                    winner = "Tie";
                } else if(playChoice == 2) {
                    winner = playerName;
                } else if(playChoice == 0) {
                    winner = "Computer";
                }

            case 2:
                if(playChoice == 1) {
                    winner = "Computer";
                } else if(playChoice == 2) {
                    winner = "Tie";
                } else if(playChoice == 0){
                    winner = playerName;
                }

        } //closes the switch

        return winner;
    }
}
```

This is my first major program, so I apologize for any glaring errors or incorrectly-interpreted concepts. I think my major issue lies in the return types, but I'm not positive.

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, that means there should be a compilation error. Include that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through your code, it is a bit of a mess, so I'll go through step by step.

```
game.setPlayers();
game.convertUserInput(response);
game.setPlayerChoice(response);
game.computerThink();
game.determineWinner();
```

You call ALL of these, yet some have return types and are called in previous functions already. For example, `convertUserInput`.

Your `convertUserInput` function sets the `playChoice` variable, declares it returns a String but actually returns nothing. This is called with your clump of functions above, but is then also called by `setPlayerChoice`, which replaces the `playChoice` set in the call with, well, nothing. Because nothing is returned you get a compile error.

`computerThink` returns an int, but you call it above without setting the returned value to anything, then `determineWinner` is called, which WOULD work had it not been for the above problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit wrong with your code. A few obvious ones: you have parameterized your setPlayers method of the RockPaperScissors class to accept a string, but when you invoke it, you dont provide any value, thats a compile time issue. In the RockPaperScissors class you have a method convertUserInput whose method signature says it will return a string, but there are no code paths which return a value in that method. I would do a few more simple tutorials to try to wrap your head around basic OOP concepts then come back to this once you understand basic stuff like, What is an Object? What is a method signature? and most importantly, read and interpret the compile time errors.

Comment: First "problem" isn't a problem, there's an import static that covers that.

Comment: Good eye, I didnt copy the imports. -Edited to correct

Answer (score 0):

It's a little strange that you know your problem lies with the return types but don't know how to fix it. Are you just reading the error message but don't know what its actually saying?

The `return type` is declared in the first line of a method, the `method declaration`. The method is expected to `return` the `return type` or you will receive a compile-time error.

---

**Some Examples**

```
//these are method declarations
//    the return type is before the name of the method
public void setPlayers(String player) {} //return type "void" - this method should not return anything

public String convertUserInput(String response) { // return type "String" - this method NEEDS to return a String
    return "A String";
}
```

**Matching method calls**

```
//You need to match the return type with how you call the method

String myPlayers = setPlayers("player"); //WON'T COMPILE - setPlayers returns void, not String

setPlayers("player"); // this is okay, nothing is returned, return type void

String convertedInput = convertUserInput("response"); // this is okay, return type String, which is what convertedInput will be.

convertUserInput("response"); // this is also okay, even though it returns a String we don't have to assign it to a variable. Though in this example calling the method like this is pretty much useless.

int convertedInput = convertUserInput("response"); //WON'T COMPILE - convertUserInput returns String, not an int.
```